# Is it doable to insert a javascript to allow me to access camera of the computer in adobe acrobat pro?

Tags: javascript, camera, adobe, acrobat

I'm relatively new to this. So i'm not sure if it is doable or not. I want to insert a button with JavaScript, which allows me to access the camera app once i click that button, and once i took a photo, it will just automatically attach this photo to that pdf files. Or maybe there 's other way to achieve this not using java script. Thanks all.

Comment: Seems doable. You could start by looking at something like this: https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs to take a picture with the webcam. Then, have a look at this to create a PDF file: https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Comment: Is this intended for devices or for computers?

Comment: I think we will use it on surface pro. So I would say computers.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to achieve this with the Javascript extensions Acrobat pro provides.

As other commenters have pointed out, there are Javascript libraries that can access a webcam, that could be used in conjunction with a pdf generator to achieve this, but it can not be done with the Acrobat Javascript API.